# (ASK) How we debug local websocket with AWS api gateway

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, debugging, lambda, websocket

I need to test my functions locally using AWS Web Socket API Gateway. Is there any possible way to mimic or duplicate the behaviour of AWS Web Socket in my local machine ? So I don't need to deploy every little changes to my Lambda function

Thanks

Answer (score 8):

Unfortunately we're still waiting on local sam support for v2 of API Gateway.

https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sam-cli/issues/896

Answer (score 2):

Recently I was able to find [here](https://github.com/aws/aws-sam-cli/issues/896#issuecomment-738822193) that there is a workaround available called [aws-lambda-ws-server](https://github.com/JamesKyburz/aws-lambda-ws-server) which wraps the routes with a websocket server when ran locally and also works deployed as a AWS Lambda.

Hopefully this will help others in the future!